# How to integrate Yoxview to Rails 3 application when pictures are protected by Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, paperclip, yoxview

I'm trying to integrate [Yoxview](http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/) to my Rails 3 application that uses [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to upload pictures.

The main problem is that the pictures (both original and thumbs) are **not in the public area**, i.e. they are accessible via Controller as described [here](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/8/29/protecting-your-paperclip-downloads).

The relevant HTML looks like:

```
<div id="my_wrapper">
  <a href="/assets/1/original"><img src="/assets/1/thumb" /></a>
  <a href="/assets/2/original"><img src="/assets/2/thumb" /></a>
</div>
```

When a thumbnail is clicked, I expect the Yoxview player to be opened, but what happens is that the original picture is opened in a browser.

When the pictures are in the public area like this:

```
<div id="my_wrapper">
  <a href="/images/originals/1.jpg"><img src="/images/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="/images/originals/2.jpg"><img src="/images/thumbs/2.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

everything works perfectly!

Any ideas ?

---

**UPDATE**

I tried also:

```
<div id="my_wrapper">
  <a href="/images/originals/1.jpg"><img src="/images/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="/images/originals/2.jpg"><img src="/images/thumbs/2.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="/assets/1/original"><img src="/assets/1/thumb" /></a>
  <a href="/assets/2/original"><img src="/assets/2/thumb" /></a>
</div>
```

Here, if I click on `thumbs/1.jpg` or `thumbs/2.jpg` the player is opened properly, but shows only these two (original) pictures. If I click on one of the other two thumbs, their original picture is opened in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. It's so simple. Just had to use the `allowedUrls` option of Yoxview:

```
allowedUrls: /^\/assets\/\d+\/(thumb|original)$/i
```